# Linked server setup between SQL Server Express and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, sql-server-2005-express

Can you please explain how to setup a linked server between a SQL Server (A) and a SQL Server Express (B) scenario.

Server A is SQL Server 2000, whereas Server B is SQL Server 2005 Express.

I have set these up in the past, but none where connected to a SQL Server Express version.

Thanks,
Billy

Comment: no problem with that.  I would like to go back and fix.  HOW DO I ACCEPT AN ANSWER????  All i see is comment and flag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this sp to do it.

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = 'MylinkedServer',
    @useself = 'FALSE',
    @locallogin = NULL,
    @rmtuser = 'me',
    @rmtpassword =  'myrmtpassword'
```

Comment: i have tried this.  I get the following error:

OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "MyServerName" returned message "Communication link failure".
Msg 10054, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 0
Login failed for user 'Me'.

Comment: This approached worked for me after i changed to the proper user.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the sp_addlinkedserver stored procedure:

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=133

Sql server Express supports linked servers