# How to create linked server from SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have two machines one is running SQL Server 2014 (Machine A) and the other one SQL Server 2012 (Machine B). Machine A has storage limitation and hence I decided to leave all databases on the Machine B so I can connect and use data from Machine A.

I set Machine B so I can connect it remotely. Now, I am able to connect from Machine A to Machine B. My problem is that, I am unable to push my data from Machine A to B. I guess I need Linked-Server. I tried to build Linked server but when I make linked server, it gives me below error:

> Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [5]. 
>   OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "192.168.0.18/SQLEXPRESS" returned message "Login timeout expired".
>   OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "192.168.0.18/SQLEXPRESS" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5)

- Linked server name is : `192.168.0.18/sqlexpress` and I set to use my user name and password.
- Machine A: Mac running Microsoft Windows on Parallel (I connect using Win 8.1 that runs over Mac Yosemite).
- Machine B: Windows 8.1 on physical server (no VM).

I have enabled **Named Pipe** from network configuration of my Machine B SQL server. However, I think I need to do some modification on port number with my Firewall.

**UPDATE:** I disabled Firewall on Machine B, but no clue yet.

Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: How did you try to setup the link? Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603463

Comment: It throws error. "The server ''  does not exist. Use sp_helpserver to show available s

Comment: What throws that error?

Answer (score 0):

It gave the same error to me

> Msg 15015, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_addlinkedsrvlogin, Line 49
>   The server '.\SQLEXPRESS' does not exist. Use sp_helpserver to show available servers.

but still created the server ,so try `.\SQLEXPRESS` and see..!!

Also, if this doesn't work try

`EXEC sp_helpserver`

and see the full name of the server and then see if your linked server comes there..!!

Comment: Thanks Arpit. This question is 13 month old and by now I have resolved it. So, I am unable to verify your answer since there is no more such error. So for the sake of community well being I leave it to future visitors with the same problem.Appreciate your time.